# Python 3.5 - How to do a webscraping of a javascript rendered page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to extract a javascript rendered table using python 3 and a webdriver.

My code is the following :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://esploracolfis.sns.it/EsploraCoLFIS/#!0:t=L&l=1;1:r=T")
driver.refresh()
# Wait for the dynamically loaded elements to show up
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))

# And grab the page HTML source
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
print(html)
```

Now,when i print the body the javascript rendered content is not present in my print.
How can i extract the table i want (the whole html code of the table) ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve your problem was use the Beautifulsoup library to parse the source code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import bs4

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://esploracolfis.sns.it/EsploraCoLFIS/#!0:t=L&l=1;1:r=T")
driver.refresh()
# Wait for the dynamically loaded elements to show up
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))

# And grab the page HTML source
html = driver.page_source

# Turns html into a beautifulsoup object
bs4_html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Finds the table
table = bs4_html.find_all('table')

driver.quit()

print(table)
```

The console output is a mile long so I can't put it here.

Hope that helps!